# Kotlin: Compare property values of different target objects with(out) reflection

Tags: reflection, lambda, kotlin

I want to compare values between multiple instances of a data class so that I know which value changed:

```
data class A(val name : String)
val firstA = A("hello")
val secondA = A("you")

if (secondA.name.changed(firstA)) {
   // Do something
}
```

Can I somehow access the property function of `.name` and execute it on another target value (in this example on firstA) without explicitly defining it? 
Can delegates help here or how do I solve this with and without reflection?

Comment: To confirm, do you want it with or without reflection, the last sentence of the question seems like either, but the question says only without?

Comment: I changed the title, best would be without reflection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Without Reflection

I found a way without using reflection:

```
interface DiffValue<T> {
    val old : T?
}

fun <T,R> T.changed(memberAccess : T.() -> R) : Boolean {
    if (this is DiffValue<*>) {
        val old = this.old as? T
        if (old != null) {
            val currentValue = with(this, memberAccess)
            val previousValue = with(old, memberAccess)
            return currentValue != previousValue
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And this is how you use it:

```
data class A(val name: String, override val old : A? = null): DiffValue<A>
val firstA = A("hello")
val secondA = A("you", firstA)

if (secondA.changed {name}) {
   // Do something
}
```

This is based on the concept of [lambda literals with receivers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) that allows Kotlin to build powerful builders and DSLs.

Note: The `DiffValue` interface is optional and is just used to make it a bit easier to keep values together and avoids an additional parameter in `changed`.

Comment: I like this very much, you can also write a simple `Diff` class that takes two objects to avoid the additional paramater. Btw, I tried writing a `fun <R> changedAny(memberAccess: Array<T.() -> R>): Boolean` function. Can write one that seems ok, but whenever I try to use I see errors. Is it possible to have a `changedAny` function?

Comment: @joecks one shouldn't need to change an object to be able to diff it, e.g. this cannot be applied to third party libs in its current form. `T.changed(T, T.() -> R)` would allow to remove the interface, the modification and make it usable with any type.

Comment: @prom85 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847961/253468

Answer (score 7):

## Using reflection

Using the Kotlin reflection library you can use the `memberProperties` and filter by different values

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

data class Example(val a: Int, val b:Long, val c: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val start = Example(1,2, "A")
    val end = Example(1,4, "B")
    val differentFields = Example::class.memberProperties.filter {
        val startValue = it.get(start)
        val endValue = it.get(end)
        !Objects.equals(startValue, endValue)
    }

    differentFields.forEach {
        println(it.name)
    }
}
```

Output

```
b
c
```

## Not using reflection

You need to explicitly go over each method (or store them in a list and iterate over them)

### Without List

```
import java.util.*

data class Example(val a: Int, val b:Long, val c: String) {
    fun getChanged(other: Example): List<String> {
        val ret: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

        if (!Objects.equals(a, other.a)) ret.add("a")
        if (!Objects.equals(b, other.b)) ret.add("b")
        if (!Objects.equals(c, other.c)) ret.add("c")

        return ret
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val start = Example(1,2, "A")
    val end = Example(1,4, "B")
    println(start.getChanged(end))
}
```

### With List

```
import java.util.*

data class Example(val a: Int, val b:Long, val c: String) {

    data class Field(val function: (Example) -> Any?, val name: String)
    val fields: List<Field> = listOf(
            Field({ it.a }, "a"),
            Field({ it.b }, "b"),
            Field({ it.c }, "c")
    )

    fun getChanged(other: Example): List<String> {
        return fields.filter {
            !Objects.equals(it.function(this), it.function(other))
        }.map { it.name }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val start = Example(1,2, "A")
    val end = Example(1,4, "B")
    println(start.getChanged(end))
}
```

Comment: That are two nice answers, thanks for your help but it is not really helping because I am not scoping the second value: `secondA.name.changed(firstA)`. Also unfortunately the second solution is not really scalabel solution.

Comment: Is the with list option more usable?

Comment: I found a solution that is a bit more scalable, but thanks for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805891/495800

Answer (score 0):

### Without Reflection - generalized

Followup based on joecks' answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805891/253468
Replying to [Kotlin: Compare property values of different target objects with(out) reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792185/kotlin-compare-property-values-of-different-target-objects-without-reflection/46792462#comment93369262_46805891)

> I tried writing a fun  changedAny(memberAccess: Array<T.() -> R>): Boolean function. Can write one that seems ok, but whenever I try to use I see errors. Is it possible to have a changedAny function?

I think your problem was that `<R>` couldn't be inferred because different properties have different types, and `R` can only have one value per function call. Simply erasing the type parameter makes it work, Kotlin will still call `.equals()` just as before.

```kotlin
fun <T> T.changed(other: T, memberAccess: T.() -> Any?): Boolean {
    val currentValue = with(this, memberAccess)
    val previousValue = with(other, memberAccess)
    return currentValue != previousValue
}

fun <T> T.changedAny(other: T, vararg memberAccesses: T.() -> Any?): Boolean =
    memberAccesses.any { changed(other, it) }
```

Using vararg instead of `Array` makes the syntax simpler, and at this point `changed` is almost not necessary unless you want to ever use `changed(...) { prop }` syntax.

```kotlin
data class A(val name: String, val age: Int)

val firstA = A("hello", 0)
val secondA = A("you", 1)

if (secondA.changed(firstA) { name }) {
    // Do something
}
if (secondA.changedAny(firstA, { name }, { age })) {
    // Do something
}
```

For trivial property/function accesses, you can use a property reference instead of a lambda:

```kotlin
if (secondA.changed(firstA, A::name)) {
    // Do something
}
if (secondA.changedAny(firstA, A::name, A::age)) {
    // Do something
}
```

---

By the way, there's a Kotlin stdlib function that does almost the same if your properties are `Comparable`:

```kotlin
if (compareValuesBy(firstA, secondA, A::name, A::age) != 0) {
    // Do something
}
```